# I have multiple points at the same position which I want to merge

Tags: qgis

I have multiple points at the same geographical position that represent pick up points for a goods vehicle. There are approximately 8 fields of data for each point as the attribution, eg date, time, type of freight etc. I want to be able to merge all the points together so I have a single point with multiple rows of data so if you click on that point, you see all the incidents of pick up at that point.

Comment: Is the position for each point exactly the same? Or just close? Also: what format is your data in? Shapefile? Database of some kind?

Comment: The position of the point is exactly the same. I have the data in both CSV and shapefile.

Comment: Do you want a one-time concatenation, or a relationship that would allow you to easily add more records to a given point?

Comment: And can you add to your question a sample of what your attribute table looks like?

Comment: No I don't need to add further data. It is snapshot in time.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reveal the table contents as it is commercially sensitive. It is a very simple table with 13 fields. Suffice to say that there are coords within the table that can be matched.

Comment: Understood. Sometimes having a sample of how the data is laid out, like field names, data types etc. but not necessarily real data (perhaps some fake data that's somewhat realistic) can help with a more accurate answer. I'll go ahead and post an answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend splitting the data into two layers and using a one-to-many relationship.

You'll need to separate your data into:

1. A layer containing your points and a unique identifier column.
2. A layer containing your records which reference the point's unique identifier.

First we need to make a column that's the same for each record of a given point, but guaranteed to be different then records for other points. A simple way to do this is to derive a string from its coordinates.

Open field calculator and use it to create an additional field concatenating the x and y coordinates:
[image: Field calculator X($geometry) || Y($geometry)]

This should create an extra column looking something like this:
[image: Pin column]

Next we want to create the layer containing the points and pin. My tool of choice for this would be a virtual layer. Select 'Add virtual layer' from the bar on the left. Use the import button to add your points layer then structure the query as I have here (substituting your layer name of course):
[image: SELECT DISTINCT]

This will generate a layer that only has one feature for each point and only has one column (the pin). Right-click this layer use 'save as' to save it as a shapefile. Remove the virtual layer.

Now we need to create a relationship between our original layer and the saved virtual layer. Go to project properties and open the 'Relations' tab and hit 'add relation'. Your child layer will be your original layer, and the parent layer will be our new saved virtual layer. The field in both cases will be the new one you added 'pin'.
[image: relationship screen]

Finally, we need to configure our saved virtual layer to show the related fields when selected with the 'identify' tool. Open the virtual layer's properties and select the 'Fields' tab. From the drop-down at the top change the attribute editor layout from 'Autogenerate' to 'Drag and drop designer'

Hit the green '+' to add a category for your relationship records. Your category should show on the right in the box under 'label'
Hit the black arrow to expand the 'Relations' section on the left. Your relation should show there. Drag and drop the relation into the category you created.
[image]

Now when you use the identify tool it will bring up all the related features.
[image]